# Safest communication method between applications on same machine

Tags: java, c++, security, ssl

What is the safest communication method between two applications on the same machine, both Java and C/C++ clients with a Java server.

Are SSL sockets safe enough or they can be broken by "man in the middle" attacks?

The main concern here is how the clients can trust the local server?

Would introducing a remote server improve the security of the local communication and how can this be achieved?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what attack you are trying to defend against.   If its a local system and the attacker has root/admin then there is absolutely nothing you can do, after all they already own the system which is the whole point.  In terms of SSL and MITM,  that made me chuckle,  SSL backed by a PKI was specifically built to stop attacks like MITM.

Answer (score 5):

You need to elaborate your threat model. It's a general truism that anyone with physical access to your hardware, motivation and sufficient time **will** be able to subvert anything. This goes double if that attacker happens to be an admin on the server.

And yes, anything that is in your code is readable with admin access. You can try clever tricks like encrypting or obfuscating a password stored in binaries/JAR files, but this is a hindrance, not an absolute barrier.

Again, on the other side, there are no absolute barriers for confidentiality, merely more or less efficient obstructions. Whatever your measure, whatever the strength of your encryption and key management, with enough time and incentives, anything will yield. Which returns us to my first point: what is your threat model (what attacks do you wish to protect against); how much are your protected assets worth; and whom and what do you trust?

Comment: In my particular case the clients will have to get a response from the local server based on which they will proceed on different paths so they need to trust this server.

Comment: Agreed.  This is why DRM is fundamentally flawed.  The owner of the hardware becomes the attacker, so with enough effort any DRM can be broken.  Note, I'm not trying to imply that the question has anything to do with DRM, just making an analogy.

Comment: I honestly don't think Radu knows what attack he is trying to defend against.  But this is a good answer to a bogus question.

Comment: @The Rook: Unfortunately, business people are known and infamous for expecting 'bogus' questions like these to have concrete, practical answers (which are naturally cheap and quickly implemented!). @KeithB's DRM example is just one of the more well known fallacies... But hey, let's just sprinkle the magic encryption dust and wait for the sparkles to protect us! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Safe from what? If an attacker has root, they can subvert system calls and spy on memory buffers before encryption and after decryption, and nothing you can do is safe.

If an attacker does not have root, they can't see this information even if you don't encrypt it.

So I don't see a point to this.

Answer (score 1):

If your entire system, including it's secrets are running on the same machine, then unforutnately it is intrinsicly unsafe. A hacker can see all parts of the system, and with enough effort, can unravel any protection, or encryption scheme you put in place.

If the system must be 100% secure then part of the system needs to be remote, and so unavailable to a hacker to comprimise.

Comment: if a system must be 100% secure, it must be unplugged - from the power grid as well as the network :)

Comment: Even then it is possible to read the harddrive and decrypt it, so you must lock it away in a big safe and bury it somewhere where no one expect it... But even then there a small chance that someone will find it... I think I'm getting paranoid. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say that memory-mapped files or shared memory regions are the safest method, which both [Java](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1548681/Introduction-to-Memory-Mapped-IO-in-Java.htm) and C++ ([Win32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142377), [Unix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)) support for interprocess communication. It's more complex though as you have to deal with your own synchronisation. Bypass sockets completely.

Comment: @mdma Of course at that point the entire memory space of the process is readable, so the communication mechanism is irrelevant.

Comment: @mdma how do you plan on doing that?

Answer (score 1):

A pipe should provide safe (and easy) communication.  Yes, hackers would be able to retrieve a password if it is stored in a binary and the binary's permissions allow reading the file.